# Is there a slick way to deploy my silverlight app and change settings programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am fairly new to web development.  I am at the point of deployment (for testing).  I have a few places (maybe 4 places) where I had to add a URI that was non-relative into the appliation.  So now, at deployment, those need to be changed.

Is there a slick way of handling this?  By slick I mean not **manually** going through the app and changing the URIs or a blanket find and replace (too risky).  I only have 4 places to change now, but this could easily change and cause deployment issues.

I am using a Microsoft technology stack.  Silverlight, ASP.NET, RIA, etc.  Development is done in Visual Studio 2010.

I noticed that the web projects have a nifty transformation for the web.config...which is nice.  Is there an equivalent mechanism for silverlight resources?  Any other ways?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360533/dynamic-endpoints-in-servicereferences-clientconfig) concerning using MS's built in transformation mechanism for service references.  But in reality...it's generic for any XML file.  Which means I was able to apply the same concepts to my custom XML file that held some settings...and it worked brilliantly.

**See Randoms solution.**  It isn't the selected solution but it is far better than anything else I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass parameters to the Silverlight application from the hosting web page.

```
<object ....>
... 
<param name="initParams" value="prm1=http://google.com,prm2=http://bing.com" />
...
</object>
```

And access from your Silverlight app (`App.xaml.cs`, `Application_Startup` method):

```
foreach (var item in e.Initparams)
{
  this.Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Access the parameters:

```
var prm1 = App.Current.Resources["prm1"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too pretty, but you can check for the DEBUG define (defined in debug mode builds by default):

```
#if (DEBUG)
    myUrl = "http://www.google.com";
#else
    myUrl = "http://www.bing.com";
#endif
```